# Set external computer IP to environment variable

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, server

I have an external computer with an IP address like `100.12.5.7` and I would like to set a path to the environment variable like so:

```
setx MEDIA \\\100.12.5.7\d\media\
```

When I tried the above command, cmd prompt me that the variable is set successfully but when I do an `echo %MEDIA%`, it only shows me `%MEDIA%` instead of the full path. Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Setx` doesn't affect the current console. Use `Set` and `Setx` together. `Set`, unlike `Setx`, requires an equal sign.

The reason setx can't affect the current console is that a copy of the starting program's environment is passed to programs it starts (usually Explorer's environment either direct or indirect via CMD). So all changes are local to that program. `Setx` sets registry keys, so only new programs can read them, and that really mean CMD.exe, as that rereads the registry keys.